I'm consuming an ASP.NET Core Web API in a MVC app but I get error
Error:

'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Mvc_Web_Application.Models.PostViewModel

public class BlogController : Controller
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7181/api");

    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public BlogController()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        _client.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            CustomActionResult < PostViewModel > posts = new CustomActionResult<PostViewModel>();
            HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync(_client.BaseAddress + "/Blog/GetBlogs").Result;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
            { 
                string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <CustomActionResult<PostViewModel>>(data);
                return View(posts);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        return View();
    }
}

I have a custom model CustomActionResult and it add "is-success" and "message" to the end of data I tried CustomActionResult<PostViewModel> but it didn't work either.
My data format is like this:
{
    "data": 
       [
        {
            "title": "test1",
            "body": "body",
            "author": null,
            "id": 1,
            "createdDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "updatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
            "title": "test1",
            "body": "body1",
            "author": null,
            "id": 2,
            "createdDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
            "updatedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
     ],
     "isSuccess": true,
     "message": null
}

PostViewModel :
public class CustomActionResult
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class CustomActionResult<T> : CustomActionResult
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}

CustomActionResult:
public class CustomActionResult
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class CustomActionResult<T> : CustomActionResult
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}


Can you also share PostViewModel and CustomActionResult

I guess you need List<PostViewModel> data instead of PostViewModel data in the model.

You've added CustomActionResult and CustomActionResult<T> twice!

Can you share how your PostViewModel is defined? Currently only see CustomActionResult

The error you are facing is deserialization of JSON array into a single object.
I have updated the code below.
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = _client.GetAsync(_client.BaseAddress + "/Blog/GetBlogs").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        { 
            string data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            
            CustomActionResult<List<PostViewModel>> posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomActionResult<List<PostViewModel>>>(data);

            return View(posts);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    return View();
}

